# Get/Set innerHTML in Perl HTML::TreeBuilder?

Tags: perl, innerhtml

Get/Set innerHTML in Perl HTML::TreeBuilder? I could get innerHTML but dont know how to set.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this approach will satisfy you, but you can use [html($html)](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm#html%28%29_html%28$html%29) method from [pQuery](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/pQuery-0.07/lib/pQuery.pm):

> This method is akin to the famous
>   JavaScript/DOM function innerHTML.
>
> If called with no arguments, this will
>   return the the inner HTML string of
>   the first DOM element in the pQuery
>   object.
>
> If called with an HTML string
>   argument, this will set the inner HTML
>   of all the DOM elements in the pQuery
>   object.

As far as why pQuery may satisfy you, to quote from POD:

> pQuery::DOM is roughly an attempt to
>   duplicate JavaScript's DOM in Perl. It
>   subclasses
>   HTML::TreeBuilder/HTML::Element so
>   there are a few differences to be
>   aware of. See the pQuery::DOM
>   documentation for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use pQuery, but this will work

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = <<'__HTML__';
<div id="target">old <B>i</B><I>n</I>ner</div>
__HTML__

{
    my $t = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($html);

    print $t->as_HTML('<>&',' ',{}), "\n";

    my $target = $t->look_down( id => 'target' );
    $target->delete_content;
    $target->push_content(
        HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content(
            "<B>NEW</B>"
        )->look_down(qw!_tag body!)->detach_content
    );

    print $t->as_HTML('<>&',' ',{}), "\n";

}
__END__
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="target">old <b>i</b><i>n</i>ner</div>
 </body>
</html>

<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="target"><b>NEW</b></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Yes, I RTFM

Comment: Works perfect, it even links back _parent. Thanks